# urllib.request.Request - unexpected keyword argument 'method'

Tags: python, methods, request, urllib

Attempting to use the `method` argument as seen [here](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request) yields the following error.

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Sep 25 2013, 18:22:43)
>>> import urllib.request as r
>>> r.Request('http://example.com', method='POST')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method'
>>>
```

No matter what/where I search, I can't seem to find a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the docs for Python 3.3 but running Python 3.2.  In Python 3.2 the `Request` initializer doesn't have a `method` argument: http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request

FWIW depending on what kind of request you make (for example if the request includes a body) `urllib` will automatically use the appropriate method (i.e. POST).  If you need to make a more specialized type of request such as `HEAD` you need to dig a little deeper.  There are other answers on SO that help with that.

Comment: Ah, I failed to see the `3.3.3` selected at the top of the doc page. Thanks!